# Meaning of tags in Lucene parser exceptions

Tags: parsing, syntax, lucene

I want to display human readable parse errors from Lucene.
Hidden in the suppressed exceptions in ElasticsearchException is some genuinely useful information on what caused a parser error. e.g.

```
"Encountered \"<EOF>\" at line 1, column 32.\nWas expecting one of:\n    <AND> ...\n    <OR> ...\n    <NOT> ...\n    \"+\" ...\n    \"-\" ...\n    <BAREOPER> ...\n    \"(\" ...\n    \")\" ...\n    \"*\" ...\n    \"^\" ...\n    <QUOTED> ...\n    <TERM> ...\n    <FUZZY_SLOP> ...\n    <PREFIXTERM> ...\n    <WILDTERM> ...\n    <REGEXPTERM> ...\n    \"[\" ...\n    \"{\" ...\n    <NUMBER> ...\n    "
```

The  are from QueryParserConstants and for most of them it is obvious what part of the query syntax they they refer to e.g. CARAT => ^
but some are not so obvious:

```
<BAREOPER>, <PREFIXTERM>, <REGEXPTERM>, <RANGE_GOOP>
```

In QueryParserConstants, these names are mapped to integer references to regex terms but, despite having examined the Lucene source code, I still cannot figure out what these ones mean.

Does anyone recognise what these refer to or know where in the code I can find the relevant regex terms, so I can work it out from those?

Comment: In case you have not already seen this, you can find the token definitions [here](https://github.com/apache/lucene/blob/d5d6dc079395c47cd6d12dcce3bcfdd2c7d9dc63/lucene/queryparser/src/java/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/QueryParser.jj#L179). Not sure if this helps...

Comment: @andrew.james Thank you. I had not managed to find that file but have now.